# moved domain name - only home page works

Tags: .htaccess, magento, mod-rewrite, hyperlink

I moved a site to a magento new domaine name.
Home page works well but all the links give 404.

I verified that "*LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so*" is enabled in httpd.conf

.htaccess has this entry:

```
## rewrite everything else to index.php
RewriteRule .* index.php [L]
```

**old site**

```
http://old_site.com/                    << this works
http://old_site.com/en/contentpage.html         << this works
```

**new site**

```
http://newsite.com/shop1/en
http://newsite.com/shop1/en/contentpage.html     << this is a typical link from the home page                                    
                                                 << link from new site takes me here, but this gives 404 error

http://newsite.com/shop1/index.php/en/contentpage.html  < this link, however, does works
http://newsite.com/shop1/en/contentpage.html            << link from new site takes me here, but this gives 404 error
```

.

Comment: What's the "link from new site" look like? Is it an absolute URL with a fully qualified domain name? Is it just an absolute URL (begins with `/`) or is it a relative URL (doesn't begin with `/`), and what's the URL of the page with the link you are clicking on?

Comment: Have you changed the base url in the database to match the new domain?  That is the first, most common mistake.

Comment: Jon - I added additional info above.

Comment: cwGeek - changed base url in two places in setup table in datbase. (otherwise I probably would not see anything!)

Answer (score 0):

Based on the description you've provided, it look like the *Use apache rewrites* option wasn't set during the installation, or get lost somewhere.

Check for path `web/seo/use_rewrites` in the `core_config_data` table - it should have value **1**, if it doesn't, set it to 1.

Comment: Backend works properly so i was able to check there. Use Web Server re-writes is enabled.